# CMN0420E: The following command exception has occurred during processing

Tags: websphere-portal, websphere-commerce, wcs

I am getting error when hit the  site (WCS store) URL.

CMN0420E: The following command exception has occurred during processing: "com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.exception.RESTInvokeException". org.apache.commons.json.JSONException: Error occurred during input read.

Comment: what store are you using as the default, need to see the full stack trace to see what is going on

Comment: you're going to need to provide a lot more info.  What page, what does the log say, etc.